# Expected method body errors inconsistency

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am new to iOS development and I am following a book to learn it. I'm confused as to why I am getting this error. I followed the code in the book perfectly. 
I am using Xcode 6.

[image]

Sometimes when I move the braces around the errors move around...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `)` at the end of your definition (just after `sender`).